# Replace "1" with "0" and "0" with "1" simultaneously in R

Tags: r, regex, string, replace, gsub

I have a character vector in R such as:

```
> row
"1/1" "0/0" "0/0" "1/1" "0/1" "0/0" "1/0"
```

I would like to swap the "1" and "0" characters in order to return a vector:

```
> row2
"0/0" "1/1" "1/1" "0/0" "1/0" "1/1" "0/1"
```

I feel like this is a simple task, but I am getting confused since I assume multiple calls to `gsub` for instance will reverse the conversion process on the second call.

Any ideas for an R-based solution to this?  Thanks!

Comment: @GruelingPine185  I think you just fell into the hole ScottB is afraid of: after your second call everything is zero: the the original zeros became ones, and then all ones (which will be everything) become zero.

Comment: Omg. In my head everything works out, but gosh I didn't catch that. Thx for bringing it to my attention :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `chartr` :

```
row <- c("1/1", "0/0", "0/0", "1/1", "0/1", "0/0", "1/0" )
chartr('01', '10', row)
#[1] "0/0" "1/1" "1/1" "0/0" "1/0" "1/1" "0/1"
```

Comment: "There is always a base R function for it I almost surely forgot about"  :)  Equivalent to / inspired by the command-line `tr` command I suppose.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a ton!